# Merge two unsorted text files based on the first column of the first one and preserving the order

Tags: linux, bash, file, text, merge

On Linux, how can I merge two unsorted text files based on the first column of the first file and preserving the order (from the first file).

The first one:

```
DAC
CAD
ADC
BAC
```

The second one:

```
CAD:word
DAC:dog
BAC:house
```

Merged files:

```
DAC:dog
CAD:word
ADC
BAC:house
```

As I said, the lines of the merged file must be in the same order of the first file.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try awk:

```
awk -F: 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next}{if($1 in a){print a[$1];} else {print;}}' file2 file1
```

The "-F:" sets the field separator to a colon. The bit in curly braces after "FNR==NR" applies only while processing file2. It saves the whole line in an associative array "a" indexed by whatever is in field1 to the left of the colon. The bit in the second set of curly braces applies to file1. As each line is read, I check to see if the "word" is in the associative array "a" I created when reading file2, and if it is, I print the whole line I found in file2, if not, I just print the current line from file 1.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. Works just fine on small lines, but it doesn't seem to work if the lines from file1 are 31 characters long. Any idea?

Comment: Please update your question, using the "edit" button, to show some data that my solution fails with and I will have another look for you.

Comment: It works, sorry. One of the two text files was created on windows while the other was created on Linux. I had to remove \r.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution with `join` :

```
$ join -t":" -a1 -a2 -11 -21 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
AD:word
ADC
BAC:house
CAD
DAC:dog
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but i need it in the same order of file1.